# File creation in PHP getting content from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a website where the user is supposed to enter a short text in a textarea aswell as entering their e-mail and a personal id. I am trying to send this through javascript in one variable. Problem is when Irun the code no file is created. Here is the code I am using.

```
    function load(){
       var xmlhttp;
       if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
              xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
           }else{
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


    var textToSend=document.forms["form"].id.value + " "+document.forms["form"].mail.value+" "+document.forms["form"

xmlhttp.open("GET","serverside.php?txt="+textToSend,"true");
xmlhttp.send();
   }



    <?php
    $txt=$_GET["txt"];
    $spacing="\n \n";

    $my_file = 'userdata.txt';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file: '.$my_file);
    fwrite($handle, $txt);
    fclose($handle);

    ?>
```

Comment: You should be using `POST` when submitting data like this.

Comment: Don't you need a full path to the file? Like "/var/www/myapp/files/userdata.txt"

Comment: Try echo-ing the value of `$txt` to check that some of it hasn't been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee any of these will fix the problem, but you should try them:
1) using `POST` instead of `GET`
2) instead of `$my_file='userdata.txt'` try `$my_file='./userdata.txt'`
3) having `w` instead of `a` in `fopen`

Answer (score 0):

The `fopen` function does not create files by default -- it fails with "No such file or directory" error. You say that "no file is created", so I believe you didn't create the userdata.txt file manually.

Create empty userdata.txt file and see if that helps.